Persisting changes to database backend using ibis-framework
I am experimenting with the Ibis framework: it seems a great tool to work on tables that already contain data that I need to join, filter, aggregate, etc.
However, I do not find how to persist changes into the database.
As far as I understand, Ibis Tables are immutable objects that represent the steps I want to go through to analyze my data. Each time I add a new step, a new Table object is created, built starting from the previous one.
Once I have described the flow, I can run all the steps calling ibis_table.execute().
Therefore, in my current understanding, in Ibis the term 'table' does not have the same meaning as in 'database table', instead, it is something much more similar to a SQL statement (actually, they are compiled to SQL statements).
Question 0: please confirm that my current understanding is correct.
Now, consider a DuckDb database with an already populated table person
import ibis

con = ibis.connect('duckdb://mydb.ddb')
person_table = con.table('person')

Questions:

How do I insert new rows in this table? In my use case new rows may come either from a python object or they may be the result of the execution of some query via another ibis table.

How do I delete rows from this table?

Suppose I need to change the shape of an underlying database table (persisting those changes on the disk, i.e. something I would typically do with an ALTER TABLE ... statement in SQL). Can I achieve the same using ibis? How?


Thanks a lot!
